# non-recurring table join

Tags: sql-server, join

I have 2 tables "orders" and "sales". The productCode field is common in this table.

My goal is to "join" 2 tables side-by-side as follows.

[image]

What I've Tried

1. partion by (row_number() over (partition by productCode order by id))
2. GROUPING SETS
3. full outer join
4. ...CURRENT ROW AND 1 FOLLOWING..

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[orders](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [orderDate] [date] NULL,
    [productCode] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [qty] [float] NULL,
    [price] [float] NULL,
    [deadLine] [date] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_orders] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[sales](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [salesDate] [date] NULL,
    [productCode] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [qty] [float] NULL,
    [price] [float] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_sales] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[orders] ON 
INSERT [dbo].[orders] ([id], [orderDate], [productCode], [qty], [price], [deadLine]) VALUES (1, CAST(N'2022-10-01' AS Date), N'a', 10, 15, CAST(N'2022-12-01' AS Date))
INSERT [dbo].[orders] ([id], [orderDate], [productCode], [qty], [price], [deadLine]) VALUES (2, CAST(N'2022-10-02' AS Date), N'b', 20, 25, CAST(N'2023-01-01' AS Date))
INSERT [dbo].[orders] ([id], [orderDate], [productCode], [qty], [price], [deadLine]) VALUES (3, CAST(N'2022-10-03' AS Date), N'c', 30, 35, CAST(N'2023-02-02' AS Date))
INSERT [dbo].[orders] ([id], [orderDate], [productCode], [qty], [price], [deadLine]) VALUES (4, CAST(N'2022-10-04' AS Date), N'd', 40, 45, CAST(N'2023-03-03' AS Date))
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[orders] OFF


SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[sales] ON 
INSERT [dbo].[sales] ([id], [salesDate], [productCode], [qty], [price]) VALUES (1, CAST(N'2022-11-01' AS Date), N'a', 3, 14)
INSERT [dbo].[sales] ([id], [salesDate], [productCode], [qty], [price]) VALUES (2, CAST(N'2022-11-02' AS Date), N'b', 4, 25)
INSERT [dbo].[sales] ([id], [salesDate], [productCode], [qty], [price]) VALUES (3, CAST(N'2022-11-03' AS Date), N'a', 1, 16)
INSERT [dbo].[sales] ([id], [salesDate], [productCode], [qty], [price]) VALUES (4, CAST(N'2022-11-04' AS Date), N'b', 3, 20)
INSERT [dbo].[sales] ([id], [salesDate], [productCode], [qty], [price]) VALUES (5, CAST(N'2022-11-05' AS Date), N'b', 8, 24)
INSERT [dbo].[sales] ([id], [salesDate], [productCode], [qty], [price]) VALUES (6, CAST(N'2022-11-06' AS Date), N'a', 5, 24)
INSERT [dbo].[sales] ([id], [salesDate], [productCode], [qty], [price]) VALUES (7, CAST(N'2022-11-07' AS Date), N'b', 41, 20)
INSERT [dbo].[sales] ([id], [salesDate], [productCode], [qty], [price]) VALUES (8, CAST(N'2022-11-08' AS Date), N'd', 10, 35)
INSERT [dbo].[sales] ([id], [salesDate], [productCode], [qty], [price]) VALUES (9, CAST(N'2022-11-09' AS Date), N'a', 4, 10)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[sales] OFF
```

| id | orderDate | productCode | qty | price | deadLine |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-10-01 | a | 10 | 15 | 2022-12-01 |
| 2 | 2022-10-02 | b | 20 | 25 | 2023-01-01 |
| 3 | 2022-10-03 | c | 30 | 35 | 2023-02-02 |
| 4 | 2022-10-04 | d | 40 | 45 | 2023-03-03 |

| id | salesDate | productCode | qty | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-11-01 | a | 3 | 14 |
| 2 | 2022-11-02 | b | 4 | 25 |
| 3 | 2022-11-03 | a | 1 | 16 |
| 4 | 2022-11-04 | b | 3 | 20 |
| 5 | 2022-11-05 | b | 8 | 24 |
| 6 | 2022-11-06 | a | 5 | 24 |
| 7 | 2022-11-07 | b | 41 | 20 |
| 8 | 2022-11-08 | d | 10 | 35 |
| 9 | 2022-11-09 | a | 4 | 10 |

[db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UeeWSLzL)

Comment: I think you have forgotten to include your query attempts and indicate why they are not acceptable to you.

Comment: full join sample: https://dbfiddle.uk/dopi_vpV repeats the orders table repeatedly.

Comment: row_number sample: https://dbfiddle.uk/AzYIro1i repetition problem. and there is a matching problem between orders without sales and sales without orders.

Comment: You need to show it in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're half way there with using a `FULL JOIN`, you just need one extra step of blanking out the repeated rows. You can do this by using the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to enumerate the rows within each group of `productCode`s and then using a `CASE` statement or the `IFF()` function to blank out the fields when it's not the first row within the group, like so:

```
WITH _SalesOrders AS
(
    SELECT 
        o.id AS OrderId,
        o.orderDate,
        o.productCode AS OrderProductCode,
        o.qty AS OrderQuantity,
        o.price AS OrderPrice,
        o.deadLine,
        s.id,
        s.salesDate,    
        s.productCode,
        s.qty,
        s.price,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY o.productCode ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS RowId
    FROM orders o
    FULL OUTER JOIN sales s 
        ON o.productCode = s.productCode
)

SELECT
    IIF(RowId = 1, OrderId, '') AS id,
    IIF(RowId = 1, orderDate, '') AS orderDate,
    IIF(RowId = 1, OrderProductCode, '') AS productCode,
    IIF(RowId = 1, OrderQuantity, '') AS qty,
    IIF(RowId = 1, OrderPrice, '') AS price,
    IIF(RowId = 1, deadLine, '') AS deadline,
    id,
    salesDate,  
    productCode,
    qty,
    price
FROM _SalesOrders
ORDER BY productCode, RowId
```

By the way, notice in the window function, the `ORDER BY (SELECT 1)` clause. That's a nondeterministic sort clause. Feel free to replace it with the fields you want to use to define the order of the `RowId`s within each partition of `productCode`s, or leave it as is if you don't care about the order.